# GemFire server service hangs in cluster mode

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am upgrading GemFire from `8.X.X` to GemFire `9.5.2`.  I am using `spring-data-gemfire`, version `2.1.9.RELEASE`.

When I start the service, the first service within the cluster comes up fine. However, the second service simply hangs. I don't see any exception in the service of the GemFire logs.

Has anyone faced similar issue?

We haven't changed any properties, which we were using in the older version.  I wonder why it doesn't work with new GemFire version?

Answer (score 1):

> We havnt changed any properties which we were using in the older version, wonder why it doesnt work with new gemfire version.

Keep in mind that you're doing a major version upgrade (`8.X.Y` to `9.X.Y`), so backward compatibility is not fully guaranteed. I'd suggest to go through [Upgrade from Version 8.2 to Version 9](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/gemfire/getting_started/upgrade/upgrade_standalone.html) and make sure you haven't missed anything.

Moreover, and according to the [Spring Data for Pivotal GemFire Version Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-for-Pivotal-GemFire-Version-Compatibility-Matrix), `spring-data-gemfire-2.1.9` is not listed as fully compatible with `GemFire 9.5.2`, you should stick to that matrix and avoid overriding the version provided by `spring-data-gemfire`.

If the above still doesn't solve the issue, you should probably set the `log-level` as `fine` and take some thread dumps from the stuck member to see what's going on.

Cheers.